# Rbenv is not creating shim for local gem

Tags: rubygems, rbenv

I've created the gem by bundler

```
bundle gem mygem
  Creating gem 'mygem'...
  ...

rake build
  mygem 0.1.0 built to pkg/mygem-0.1.0.gem.

rake install:local
  mygem 0.1.0 built to pkg/mygem-0.1.0.gem.
  mygem (0.1.0) installed.

gem list mygem
  *** LOCAL GEMS ***
  mygem (0.1.0)

gem which mygem
  /Users/megas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mygem-0.1.0/lib/mygem.rb

rbenv rehash

which mygem
  mygem not found

rbenv shims | grep mygem #=> empty
```

As you can see, the `mygem` is installed but `rbenv` didn't create a shim for it.

What am I missing here?

```
gem env                                                                                                                                                    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.0 (2017-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/megas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/megas/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/megas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/megas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/megas/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/megas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-17
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/megas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /Users/megas/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org"]
     - :benchmark => false
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/megas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec
     - /Users/megas/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/megas/.cargo/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /Users/megas/.yadr/bin
     - /Users/megas/.yadr/bin/yadr
     - /usr/local/opt/fzf/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It necessary to create gem with `exe` option.

```
bundle gem mygem --exe
```